# Append character in front of a number + varchar

Tags: sql-server, string, varchar

I have a table named Table1 which has a varchar, named Col1. I want to create a Table2 and add a leading "0" in front of the contents of Col1.

How can I add a zero character to the front of a varchar? I have tried several ways but none seems to work.

Comment: show a sample of what you have already done in your code/sql and where you are having the issue.

Comment: I did this: select RIGHT('00000000000' + convert (varchar, dbo.[kyc2].walletno), 11) it showed following error: _The multi-part identifier "dbo.kyc2.walletno" could not be bound._ And I could not figured out how I can create a new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query will create table2 with leading "0" for col1.

```
 select '0' + Col1 Col1 into table2
 from table1
```

If table2 is already created and you want to just populate data.

```
 insert into table2(Col1)
 select '0' + Col1
 from table1
```

Comment: My table was not created. so I used your first code. But it gives this error: _An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name._ Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Edited my first answer. Need to add alias name for the first column.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to add 100 zeros, you can do:

```
select replicate('0', 100)+col1
. . .
```

If you want leading zeros with a given length, then combine this with `right()`:

```
select right(replicate('0', 10)+col1, 10)
. . .
```

If you need to insert these into another table, use `insert` or `update` on that table instead of `select`.

Comment: It says: _The right function requires 2 argument(s)._ when I used the second code.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want

```
insert into newTable select concat('0',col1),  ........... FROM oldTable
```

Comment: `CONCAT` is SQL Server 2012+ only.